# Reading from a file - how to?

Tags: java, android, file, nullpointerexception

im new in android and i tried to an application which use bluetooth for do a scan and control if the line which i red in the file equals to the name of the device which i found, but i can't do that because use readLine() generate an error: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.BufferedReader.readLine()' on a null object"
and i don't know how to resolve it.

```
package com.pack.regele;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class readFromFile{
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();

BufferedReader br;

{
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("com/pack/regele/alunniScuola.csv"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

ArrayAdapter<String> nomi = null;

public readFromFile(ArrayAdapter <String> nomi){
    this.nomi = nomi;
}

public void controllaAlunnoDellaClasse() throws IOException {
    String line, classeCercare = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        line = br.readLine();
        String[] splitta = line.split(",");
        while(line != null){
            if(splitta[0].equals(nomi.getItem(i))){
                classeCercare = contaAlunniClasse(splitta[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    stampaClasse(classeCercare);
}

public String contaAlunniClasse(String classe){
    int[] contatoreClasse = new int[8];
    switch(classe){
        case "3A": contatoreClasse[0]++; break;
        case "3B": contatoreClasse[1]++; break;
        case "3C": contatoreClasse[2]++; break;
        case "4A": contatoreClasse[3]++; break;
        case "4B": contatoreClasse[4]++; break;
        case "4C": contatoreClasse[5]++; break;
        case "5A": contatoreClasse[6]++; break;
        case "5B": contatoreClasse[7]++; break;
    }
    int max = controllaClasseMax(contatoreClasse);
    return controllaLaClasse(max);
}

public int controllaClasseMax(int[] contatoreClassi){
    int max = contatoreClassi[0], classeMaggiore = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < contatoreClassi.length; i++){
        if(contatoreClassi[i] > max){
            max = contatoreClassi[i];
            classeMaggiore = i;
        }
    }
    return classeMaggiore;
}

 public String controllaLaClasse(int max){
    switch(max){
        case 0: return "3A";
        case 1: return "3B";
        case 2: return "3C";
        case 3: return "4A";
        case 4: return "4B";
        case 5: return "4C";
        case 6: return "5A";
        case 7: return "5B";
    }
    return null;
 }

 public void stampaClasse(String classeStampare) throws IOException {
    String line = br.readLine();
    String[] arraySplit = line.split(",");
    while(line != null){
        if(arraySplit[1].equals(classeStampare)){
            nomi.add(line);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

this is my class, and the line 32 generate me the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
if (br != null) {
    line = br.ReadLine();
    String[] splitta = line.split(",");
}
```

To check if br is null first

Answer (score 1):

Let's read the error message again:

```
"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.BufferedReader.readLine()' on a null object"
```

You are trying to invoke readLine() on a null object. On which object are you invoking readLine()? We can find it here:

```
line = br.readLine();
```

So, we found out that br is null. Why is it null? You are initializing br in the initializer block:

```
try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("com/pack/regele/alunniScuola.csv"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It looks like "com/pack/regele/alunniScuola.csv" cannot be found. In this case a FileNotFoundException will be thrown and br will not get initialized. Therefore it will be null. You are catching the Exception and therefore the program is continuing and crashing later when br is used.

Look into logcat. If I am right, you should find a FileNotFoundException in your logs.

Comment: yes, into the logcat there is a FileNotFoundException

Comment: okok now i tried to change the location of the file in the asset folder and with getAsset() it works ^^

Comment: @AntonGrigorita: I am glad that I was able to help.